# How does $\sum_{t=0}^\infty(1-\frac2n)^t\frac{e^{-n\lambda }(n\lambda)^t}{t!}=e^{-n\lambda}\sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac{[\lambda(n-2)]^t}{t!}.$

Tags: power-series

How does $$\sum_{t=0}^\infty(1-\frac2n)^t\frac{e^{-n\lambda }(n\lambda)^t}{t!}=e^{-n\lambda}\sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac{[\lambda(n-2)]^t}{t!}.$$All I see is $e^{-n\lambda}$ getting pulled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\left(1-\frac2n\right)^t\frac{(n\lambda)^t}{t!} =
\left(\frac{n-2}n\right)^t \frac{(n\lambda)^t}{t!}=
\frac{[\lambda(n-2)]^t}{t!}.
$$